# Finalization of object fields

Tags: java, finalizer

I'm having difficulty understanding the implications of sections 12.6.1 and 12.6.2 of the Java SE 8 Language specification.  I am working with a product in which Java objects manage native peers so getting finalization right (until we get a chance to do a ref-queue rewrite) is important.

It is clear, from the spec, that finalizers can be run out of order.  It is reachability with which I'm having a hard time.

I believe that the spec says this:

```
class A {
    public Object o = new Object()
    protected synchronized void finalize() throws Throwable { o = null; }
}

class B {
    A a = new A()
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        a.getClass()   // always works: a cannot be null.
        a.o.getClass() // might NPE: a's finalizer might have been run
    }
}

class C {
    A a = new A()
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        synchronized (a) {
            a.getClass()   // always works: a cannot be null.
            a.o.getClass() // always works: a.o cannot be null.
        }
    }
}
```

There are 4 assertions, above.  I would very much appreciate confirmation that they are true, or explanations for why one or more is false.

Comment: *getting finalization right* Be _extremely_ careful, as finalization should essentially be used only as a failsafe in case objects were not correctly disposed of. As you've noticed, guarantees around it are sparse. Most libraries doing the kind of thing you're talking about (e.g., SWT) explicitly require a `dispose` method or similar, and Java try-with-resources has made that much cleaner to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A.finalize` acquires the lock first, then `a.o.getClass()` will NPE even in `C`. The final assertion is incorrect.

In terms of *reachability* think of it like this: Suppose `A` and `C` were cyclically reachable, then the would reach unreachability at the "same time". So, it cannot reasonably be that `A` must be finalised before `C`.

I guess a *direct* fix could be reference counting of `A`. However, relying on GC to clear up non-memory resources isn't going to be great.

Comment: Right.  Dumb example.  C might not seize the lock on a until after a is finalized. Feh.  Do you believe the other 3 assertions to be accurate?  I don't follow your discussion of reachablity: the point is that A *might* be finalized before B or C.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike Yup. `A` might be *finalised* before `B` or `C` even though they before reference `A`. This would be true even if `A` had a field `public C c;` and `C` had a constructor `C() { a.c = this; }`.

Comment: Yes.  The constructor issue seems irrelevant, if I understand you correctly.  What seems important is that, regardless of order of finalization, neither B nor C ever sees the field 'a' as null.  The instance of A might have been finalized but the reference is never null.

Comment: I was hoping for an edit that provided direct answers to the question.  None the less, the answers are present... if buried in the comments.

Comment: I don't think your edit is correct.  The spec says that there is a happens-before between the constructor and the finalizer.  I am pretty sure that includes member initialization...

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike Yup. I think it was between last use and finalisation that I was thinking of.